# Default constructed value for STL pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std-pair

I'm trying to get the following map working:

```
enum ttype { shift, reduce }
map <string, pair<ttype, int> > lookup;
```

So this works fine, but I need a way to check whether a key was not found. So for example, something to the effect of:

```
cout << (lookup["a"]==NULL) << endl; // this is wrong, but I am trying to find a way to identify when lookup["a"] does not find a corresponding value
```

It seems that if a key is not found, map will return the default constructed value (ex, if it was mapping to a string, it would just return the empty string, and I could just check if lookup["a"] == ""  - but I have no idea what the default constructed value for std::pairs would be).

Comment: Use `find`. `operator[]` adds it if it can't find it, whereas `find` does not.

Comment: @chris so I would do lookup.find("a"), but equal to what?

Comment: To `!= lookup.end()` or use `count("a") > 0`

Comment: @user1202422, [References are great.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: @user1202422, Comparing that is for use with `find()`.

Comment: @user1202422 `lookup.find("a") != lookup.end()`

Comment: @user1202422, just rewrite your code as `cout << (lookup.find("a") == lookup.end()) << endl;`; it will print `true` if the value CAN NOT be found.

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` adds the item when not found and returns a default constructed item.  `find()` doesn't return a default constructed pair but an iterator pointing to beyond the last value of your map.

```
auto iter = lookup.find("a");
if (iter != lookup.end()) {
    std::cout << "Key was found :)" << std::endl;
    std::pair<ttype, int> result = iter->second;
    std::cout << "Result was: " << result.second << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Key was not found" << std::endl;
    // Maybe add the key to the map?
}
```

Using `find()` is a little bit more verbose but it makes it more readable (in my opinion).

Comment: operator[] adds default constructed value and returns a reference to it

Comment: @Basilevs that is correct. I changed the description to include this information. However, I believe that using ```find``` makes the code more readable.

Comment: I'd say absence of side-effects is find's best side.